# IntelliJ/Scala cannot generate code for importing a package

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Not sure if bug, feature or a failure between the monitor and the chair... but IntelliJ apparently gets confused when I'm trying to import an identifier when my code belongs to a topmost package. For example:

```
package mycompany

object Something {
  val x = new Whatever(...)
```

In this case, `Whatever` belongs to package `mycompany.impl.support.whatever` which IntelliJ definitely knows the location, since the proper location is displayed when the mouse hovers over it. However, when I press ALT-Enter for having the `import` statement inserted automagically for me... IntelliJ does nothing.

I would expect to see one of these two possibilities:

```
import impl.support.whatever.Whatever
```

or maybe

```
import _root_.mycompany.impl.support.whatever.Whatever
```

Any idea why IntelliJ cannot insert the `import` statement even though it definitely does know where the identifier is declared?

Comment: Does `import mycompany.impl.support.whatever.Whatever` not work?

Comment: You should probably open a ticket on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL

Comment: @JamesWhiteley : imports are actually relative to the current package you are in. If you are in package abc and you say "import abc.xyz", Scala understands that you are trying to import abc.abc.xyz, which is not what you'd expect. However, the matter is a bit more convoluted. It's a mix of relative addressing and also absolute addressing. In general it works because this sort of mix finds your code. Eventually you have to force absolute imports by putting \_root\_ in front of the absolute path.

Comment: @RichardGomes I understand that; I only asked because I made a project in IntelliJ and created a class `Whatever` found in the same package structure as you suggest (mycompany.impl.support.whatever.Whatever). I made an object Something in package `mycompany` like you did, using Whatever, and it found the case class fine by importing `mycompany.impl.support.whatever.Whatever`... I'm not sure why your example isn't working. Have you made any changes to IntelliJ's settings which could have had an impact on this?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley :: I've just stumbled with the something similar again. With SBT, the project compiles and runs fine, but IntelliJ ... well... this is another subject. The problem lies on A.dependsOn(B % "compile->compile;test->test;it->test;ft->test;at->test"). Seem like it's far too much complicated for IntelliJ to digest.